# Div tag that prevents click on my dropdown

Tags: javascript, css, html

I need to create a dropdown where there is a div tag over my select tag. The div has the same function as a button: it allows to unroll the dropdown if I click on it. My problem is that the div is necessarily above the select, the click is not detected. How could I do (using CSS / JS)? I would like to keep the div in the same place with the same display but that the click on the div causes the action that would make a click on the select
Here is the HTML and CSS code

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
}

.dropdown>div {
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.dropdown>select {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2rem;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <select name="text">
        <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
        <option value="value1">Value 2</option>
        <option value="value1">Value 3</option>
    </select>
    <div>
      <span>v</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please create a working snippet that demonstrate your issue.

Comment: Which `div` you are talking about, there's three... are you talking about the one with a `span` inside?

Comment: Sorry not to have specified. Yes indeed I'm talking about the one with a span inside !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add [`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to the div in question. It'll allow click events to go "through" the div as if it wasn't there at all. The click events will then be handled by the select right below it.

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
}

.dropdown>div {
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  /* ADD THIS */
  pointer-events: none;
}

.dropdown>select {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2rem;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <select name="text">
        <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
        <option value="value1">Value 2</option>
        <option value="value1">Value 3</option>
    </select>
    <div>
      <span>v</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that *covering* an input element is a good way to go. It would be much cleaner and safer if you would apply the *disabled* attribute to your input when it should not work:

```
<select disabled>
```